# Firefox has strange border/rendering artifacts with adjacent background-images

Tags: css, firefox, rendering, background-image

[See this bin.](http://jsbin.com/liqeh/1/)

In FF 28.0 I'm seeing a thin black border between the images.

I'm also seeing animation artifacts on hover. Some of the borders skip frames, while others end on a weird color value that doesn't match the image itself.

Resize your browser window a bit and you should see the artifacts.

Webkit renders fine.

Hardware is MacBook Air running 10.9.2, 1.3 Ghz i5. Graphics are Intel HD Graphics 5000 1024 MB.

Here's the relevant code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="bg-img gray" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/300');"></div>
            <div class="bg-img color" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="bg-img gray" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/g/200/300');"></div>
            <div class="bg-img color" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/300');"></div>
        </div>
        ...
        <!-- two more .columns. four per row --->
    </div> <!-- .row -->
    ...
    <!-- another .row -->
</div> <!-- .container -->
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.column {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.column:hover .color {
  opacity: 1;
}

.color, .gray {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: local;
}

.color {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease 0s;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: uh, why the downvote? I've got a bin and the question is pretty straight forward. SO guidelines say to downvote on any "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended posts". I've got a JS bin and the question is pretty straight forward. So what's the beef?

Comment: Makes sure to also include the code/html *in* the question body, reducing the test-case as much as possible.

Comment: Anyway, FWIW it Renders Correctly in FF28 (just like Chrome from what I can tell) here. I suspect that it may be related to the rendering hardware/driver itself as "weird color" sounds like incorrect pixel alignments.

Comment: @user2864740 I see. Thanks for the title edit. I added code as requested. Also added some hardware specs.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem in Firefox 29 with MacBook Air Mid 2011

Comment: Yeah it's weird. I was able to compensate a bit using the ["beyonce masonry trick"](http://metafizzy.co/blog/beyonce-seamless-fluid-image-masonry/), but that's just a hack to cover up the rendering error.